Protect Application With Traefik SSL Letsencrypt in kubernetes
I just begun learning kubernetes. I made an account in digital-ocean and started a kubernetes cluster. Then I tried following this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-site-in-kubernetes-with-cert-manager-traefik-and-let-s-encrypt. But I'm having some questions about how it works.
Right now my situation is this one:
kubectl get pods,services,deployments
NAME                                   
pod/app-frontend      
pod/app-backend       
pod/cm-acme-http-solver-qh8ms          
pod/company-service    
pod/edge-service      
pod/location-service  
pod/traefik           
pod/traefik-deployment 
pod/user-service      

NAME                                TYPE           EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)                   
service/app-frontend                LoadBalancer   app-ext-ip        3000:32459/TCP            
service/app-backend                 ClusterIP      <none>            5432/TCP                  
service/cm-acme-http-solver-fcgpr   NodePort       <none>            8089:30577/TCP            
service/company-service             ClusterIP      <none>            9003/TCP                  
service/edge-service                ClusterIP      <none>            9000/TCP                  
service/kubernetes                  ClusterIP      <none>            443/TCP                   
service/location-service            ClusterIP      <none>            9002/TCP                  
service/traefik                     LoadBalancer   traefik-ext-ip    80:32591/TCP,443:30716/TCP
service/traefik-dashboard-service   LoadBalancer   tr-dash-ext-ip    8080:31431/TCP            
service/traefik-web-service         LoadBalancer   tr-ws-ext-ip      80:31211/TCP              
service/user-service                ClusterIP      <none>            9001/TCP                  

NAME                              
deployment.apps/app-frontend     
deployment.apps/app-backend     
deployment.apps/company-service   
deployment.apps/edge-service      
deployment.apps/location-service  
deployment.apps/traefik           
deployment.apps/traefik-deployment
deployment.apps/user-service  

So I have Traefik working but not acting as proxy, the app-frontend working, but not in https, the certificates issued by letsencrypt not being used anywhere.
for example
kubectl get issuer -o wide
NAME             READY   STATUS 
challenge-http   True    The ACME account was registered with the ACME server
kubectl get certificateRequest -o wide
NAME                          APPROVED   DENIED   READY   ISSUER           REQUESTOR                                         STATUS                                                                                                 AGE
    tls-app-ingress   True                False   challenge-http   system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager   Waiting on certificate issuance from order default/tls-app-ingress-http: "pending"
kubectl get certificates
NAME                    READY   SECRET                  AGE
tls-app-ingress-http   False   tls-area-ingress-http   166m

And of course since I am learning from scratch, everything is in the default environment. How do I tell kubernetes to use Traefik as a proxy and arrive to the app-frontend via https? I'm not offended if you answer me with some documentation to read, just point me in the right direction.

First of all I suggest reading those 3 articles:
https://medium.com/@faturrahmanmakruf/configure-https-in-traefik-with-cert-manager-and-lets-encrypt-db60960e2283
https://traefik.io/blog/secure-web-applications-with-traefik-proxy-cert-manager-and-lets-encrypt/
https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/cert-manager/
here are the steps:

install traefik
install certificate manager
issue a certificate request via http challenge, don't forget to edit public dns record for that
configure and redirect http to https using traefik middleware and then configuring an ingress route to use that middleware.

